# Compact closure in $C(\overline{\omega})$ implies compact closure in $L^p(\omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, arzela-ascoli

Let $\omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with $\vert \omega \vert < \infty$ and let $\mathcal{H} \subset C(\overline{\omega})$ have compact compact closure in $C(\overline{\omega})$. Then, $\mathcal{H}$ also has compact closure in $L^p(\omega)$? Here, $C(\overline{\omega})$, the continous functions on $\overline{\omega}$, is equipped with the supreme norm.

Definitely, $C(\overline{\omega})\subset L^p(\omega)$, but if that is to work, the supreme norm would have to be equivalent to the $L^p$ norm... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The restriction mapping $C(\overline \omega)\to L^p(\omega)$ is continuous (because $\omega$ has finite measure) and contiunuous images of compact sets are compact.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much for your comment! I only tried to find the equivalence between the two norms... Thanks!